# How to achieve a “Photorealistic Camera”

Tags: compositing-nodes

I’m looking to recreate the same look that the Vray Renderer can make. Specifically with the RGB Split. I’ve tried using the Lens Distortion Node from the compositor and slightly upping the dispersion amount... but it doesn’t seem to recreate the same look as Vray. I’m wondering if there’s any possible tricks or Addons to make that photorealistic look in the compositor (or someplace else). Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Setup a few extra luxuries on your camera. Such a Depth of Field, which can sometimes be a deal breaker in photorealism. Set it up and see instant realistic results. Play around with the focal length of the digital camera on blender, see which one suits your scene better. There are tons of little settings that you can adjust to make it more believable, but remember, photorealism isn't just in the camera, its in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

LuxCoreRender is a free physically based blender renderer add-on that yields realistic results with the proper settings. I use it currently.